# How to achieve $d-$privacy considering some secrets?

Tags: attack, data-privacy, differential-privacy, indistinguishability

We have a set of secrets $S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ known to an adversary. Each $x_i \in S$ belongs to user $u_i$ who needs to obfuscate his secret using the notion of $d-$privacy defined in the following.

We assume that we have a numeric function $d(x,x^{\prime})$,  giving the distinguishability level between $x,x^{\prime}$, which depends on our scenario and the privacy guarantees we wish to express. The corresponding notion of privacy is the requirement that for an arbitrary pair $x,x^{\prime}$, we have $K(x)(O) ≤ e^{ε.d(x,x^{\prime})} K(x^{\prime})(O)$.

Our goal is that each obfuscated $x_i$, denoted by $o_i$, becomes indistinguishable at least from its $h$ closest neighbors in terms of absolute distance.
My questions are as follows:

(1) How to define our mechanism $K(x)$, including $\epsilon$ and the function $d(x,x^{\prime})$ so that it provides $d-$privacy, meaning that each $o_i$ is indistinguishable from at least its $h$ closest neighbors?
The choice of $h$ is motivated by the objective of achieving a probability of $\frac{1}{h}$ for the adversary to associate each $o_i$ with its respective $x_i$.

(2) Our goal is to maximize utility, i.e., to minimize the absolute distance between $o_i$ and $x_i$, namely $|o_{i} - x_{i}|$ (for all $x_i$ that are neighbors).

(3) Which noise distribution should we use?

Comment: What came to my mind is as follows: 

We consider the level of privacy within a radius ($r$). We say that the user enjoys d-privacy within $r$ if any two secrets $x, x^{\prime}$ at a distance at most $r$ produce observations with “similar” distributions, where the “level of similarity” depends on $d$. The idea is that $d$ represents the user’s level of privacy for that radius. 
 A mechanism satisfies x-indistinguishability iff for any radius $r$ > 0, the user enjoys εr-privacy within $r$. 
I am wondering if this idea works. If yes, then how should we define $r$, $d$ and $\epsilon$?.

Comment: What is $(O)$? What notion of distance are you considering? Is it the absolute value of the difference, with the inputs seen as integers? Do you require each $o_i$ to be *perfectly* indistinguishable from its closest neighbors?

Comment: @Geoffroy: The given formula comes from the paper "Broadening the scope of differential privacy using metrics", where $(O)$ is the set of outputs. 
By distance, I mean the absolute value of the difference, and the inputs can be fractional with a maximum of two decimal places, such as 2.34, 4.50, 6.00, etc.

My goal is to maximize utility while providing differential privacy. I am not sure if this is possible when each $o_i$ is perfectly indistinguishable from its closest neighbors!

Comment: I should add that I am not sure how to define the set $O$ exactly! My intuition is that $K(x)(O)$ is the probability that the reported obfuscated input $x$ belongs to the set $O$.